# Problems with access database in linux

Tags: linux, apache, pdo

We have a strange project that MUST interact with an MSAccess Database over a linux machine.

After reading different blogs, we have been able to make some readings over existing tables, but, if we try to make an insert or some special queries it fails with a connection has been restarted message.

I'll try to explain all what we have tried.

First of all, we have upgraded our system to the latest version of LAMP because it seems that there were some problems with odbc libraries.

After that, we added the PDO connection as described here. 
https: //gist.github.com/amirkdv/9672857

sudo nano /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[MDBTools]
Description = MDBTools Driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so.1
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so.1
FileUsage  = 1
UsageCount = 2
```

After that, we have restarted apache, and it seems that select queries work correctly.

We have use the following examples with some small modifications.
http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/pdo-select-query-fetch

Our database have a table call test with the following information:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `name` VARCHAR(50), 
  `surname` VARCHAR(50), 
  `count` INTEGER
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET autocommit=1;

INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES (1, 'john', 'smith', 100);
INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES (2, 'Mary', 'simmons', 200);
INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES (3, 'Jane', 'Black', 300);
```

If I launch the following php file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Ejemplo de ODBC</title>

<body>

<?php
$mdb_file="/var/www/Temp/Example.mdb";

$uname = explode(" ",php_uname());
$os = $uname[0];

switch ($os){
  case 'Windows':
    $driver = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}';
    break;
  case 'Linux':
    $driver = 'MDBTools';
    break;
  default:
    exit("Don't know about this OS");
}

try{
$connect_string = "Driver={$driver};DBQ={$mdb_file};";
$dataSourceName = "odbc:" . $connect_string;
$connection = new PDO($dataSourceName);

$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$query = 'SELECT id, name, surname FROM test';
$result = $connection->query($query);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) {
    // Parse the result set
    foreach($result as $row) {
        print_r ("<br>");
        print_r ($row);
    }
  }
$connection = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Exception: <br>".$e->getMessage();
  die();
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

As a result we get the following rows:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [count] => 100 [1] => 100 [name] => john [2] => john [surname] => smith [3] => smith )
Array ( [id] => 2 [0] => 2 [count] => 200 [1] => 200 [name] => Mary [2] => Mary [surname] => simmons [3] => simmons )
Array ( [id] => 3 [0] => 3 [count] => 300 [1] => 300 [name] => Jane [2] => Jane [surname] => Black [3] => Black )
```

So selects seems to work.

Now if I try an easy insert

```
$query = 'insert into test (id, count) values (4,400)';
$result = $connection->query($query);
```

I receive a message of reset connection:

```
La conexión al servidor fue reiniciada mientras la página se cargaba.

El sitio podría estar no disponible temporalmente o demasiado ocupado. Vuelva a intentarlo en unos momentos.
Si no puede cargar ninguna página, compruebe la conexión de red de su equipo.
Si su equipo o red están protegidos por un cortafuegos o proxy, asegúrese de que Firefox tiene permiso para acceder a la web.
```

So I have added debug over php

```
http:  //jrs-s.net/2012/05/24/enabling-core-dumps-on-apache2-2-on-debian/

sudo apt-get install apache2-dbg libapr1-dbg libaprutil1-dbg

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
CoreDumpDirectory /tmp/apache2-dumps

mkdir /tmp/apache2-dumps ;
chmod 777 /tmp/apache2-dumps

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And after launching my php file I see that on the dump folder I have a new core file.

So I exec sudo gdb apache2 /tmp/apache2-dumps/core

and when I get the (gdb) prompt I exec "bt" command getting the following info:

```
#0  0x00007ff38c49c3b1 in vfprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ff38c55a344 in __vsprintf_chk () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ff37cbf538f in mdb_sql_error () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmdbsql.so.2
#3  0x00007ff37cbf6cbb in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmdbsql.so.2
#4  0x00007ff37cbf6691 in mdb_sql_run_query () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmdbsql.so.2
#5  0x00007ff37d012640 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so.1
#6  0x00007ff37c4e3c4a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.1
#7  0x00007ff37ecc3d70 in SQLExecute () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1
#8  0x00007ff37e69923c in odbc_stmt_execute (stmt=0x7ff38d203338) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:173
#9  0x00007ff3861ff59c in zim_PDO_query (ht=1, return_value=0x7ff38d203280, return_value_ptr=0x0, this_ptr=0x7ff38d202dd0, return_value_used=1) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/ext/pdo/pdo_dbh.c:1134
#10 0x00007ff389201819 in dtrace_execute_internal (execute_data_ptr=<optimized out>, fci=<optimized out>, return_value_used=<optimized out>) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:97
#11 0x00007ff3892bc15e in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7ff38d1cf0c0) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:552
#12 0x00007ff3892809c8 in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7ff38d1cf0c0) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#13 0x00007ff389201706 in dtrace_execute_ex (execute_data=0x7ff38d1cf0c0) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.c:73
#14 0x00007ff389213243 in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=0x0, file_count=3) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/Zend/zend.c:1316
#15 0x00007ff3891b0f1c in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fff3030a700) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/main/main.c:2506
#16 0x00007ff3892bf6dd in php_handler (r=0x7ff38d15d0a0) at /build/buildd/php5-5.5.12+dfsg/sapi/apache2handler/sapi_apache2.c:667
#17 0x00007ff38d341008 in ap_run_handler (r=0x7ff38d15d0a0) at config.c:170
#18 0x00007ff38d3415fe in ap_invoke_handler (r=0x7ff38d15d0a0) at config.c:439
#19 0x00007ff38d357e3a in ap_process_async_request (r=0x7ff38d15d0a0) at http_request.c:317
#20 0x00007ff38d357f9f in ap_process_request (r=0x7ff38d15d0a0) at http_request.c:363
#21 0x00007ff38d3544a5 in ap_process_http_sync_connection (c=0x7ff38d165290) at http_core.c:190
#22 ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7ff38d165290) at http_core.c:231
#23 0x00007ff38d34ac48 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7ff38d165290) at connection.c:41
#24 0x00007ff389b8a633 in child_main (child_num_arg=<optimized out>) at prefork.c:704
#25 0x00007ff389b8a88c in make_child (s=0x7ff38d2adde0, slot=9) at prefork.c:800
#26 0x00007ff389b8b867 in perform_idle_server_maintenance (p=<optimized out>) at prefork.c:902
#27 prefork_run (_pconf=<optimized out>, plog=<optimized out>, s=<optimized out>) at prefork.c:1090
#28 0x00007ff38d325ed6 in ap_run_mpm (pconf=0x7ff38d2db028, plog=0x7ff38d2a9028, s=0x7ff38d2adde0) at mpm_common.c:98
#29 0x00007ff38d31f448 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fff3030ae18) at main.c:777
```

But I don't know how to continue.

Could you help me?

Comment: I've been taking a look at some forums and maybe the problem of the mdb_sql_error is a version issue. I'm using PHP Version 5.5.12-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1, System Linux 3.2.0-60-generic #91-Ubuntu x86_64. Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu). PDO Driver for MySQL version 5.5.37

Comment: Maybe this is my problem, but still don't have the solution https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2013-October/101840.html

Comment: It seems that there was a bug on mdb_sql, so I need too upgrade it. [link]https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdbtools/+bug/1227033[link]

Comment: At the end, we are going to change the way of reading the mdb files using this technique. http://www.opengurukul.com/vlc/mod/page/view.php?id=2675. There is some detail info here http://www.codediesel.com/data/migrating-access-mdb-to-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

David, hi

It's been a while since I did Access DB import into mysql and unfortunately I do not have access to that system anymore. But as far as I remember most of our strange problems where solved by switching the language settings form utf-8 to iso-8859-1 in the server configuration.

Maybe this is a point into the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for your answer metaphor_set, but at the end, as we also needed to write into access we decided to use http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/. It has several examples and its really easy to use. Anyway, maybe some in the future can try to change the language settings.